# Laravel 4.1 Eloquent using "where" with "with" to filter the related MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Attempting to emulate a `LEFT JOIN` using Eloquent and receiving an error. Basically, I am trying to get `Users` with `addresses`, but only of a certain type.

This code does not work, but I think you will get the gist:

```
$user = User::with('addresses', 'cards')->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('address.type', '=', 'shipping');
})->find(Auth::user()->id);
```

If I leave off the `where` it works fine, but more addresses returned than I need/want.

How can I make it so I only get addresses with a type = 'shipping'? I might want to do the same thing with `cards` as well. If there are no shipping addresses, I still want everything else.

I was trying to use Eloquent vs Fluent/DB (which I did make work), but just can't figure it out.

**Follow-up**: Depending on what version of PHP you have, you may need to do `array(load array)` vs. `[load array]`. Dev and Prod are not always the same.

Comment: do you only want addresses of type shipping for users. or only users with addresses of type shipping ?

Comment: I want the User and only addresses with type "shipping". But I want the user regardless of whether or not addresses are returned. I figured this out in Fluent, but in Eloquent I can't get it working. The code above can be considered pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->load(['cards', 'addresses' => function($q) {
    $q->where('type', 'shipping');
}]);
```

[Eager Loading - Constraints / Lazy Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: That's it! Learned something. Thanks.

Comment: Life really sucked before SO existed.

Answer (score 0):

This way will return your User with all their cards and only addresses where type = 'shipping'

```
$user = User::with(['cards','addresses'=>function($query){
      $query->where('type','shipping');
    }])->find(Auth::user()->id);
```